# Cursor does not change style when hovering over text in chrome developer tools in chrome

Tags: cursor, google-chrome-devtools

I was using the chrome developer tools, when I pressed a key combination and now when I hover over any text in the console, my cursor does not change into the text cursor!

This is really annoying, does anyone know what I pressed and how I can change it back?

Answer (score 4):

Open the settings for the inspector and in the "Overrides" section turn off "Emulate touch events".

Comment: A few screen shots or a little more detailed steps would make this post amazing. ;)

Comment: It was turned off already for me, but I still have no text cursor